# Trigger lambda using AWS Eventbridge on specific dates

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I want to trigger a lambda function using EventBridge on specific dates which don't have any pattern.
Let's say the dates are

> 12th Jan 2022, 29th Jan 2022, 1st Feb 2022, 14th Feb 2022, 15th March
> 2022, and 17th May 2022

How can I achieve this using EventBridge? IS it possible to pass multiple cron expressions to the eventbridge scheduler?

```
[0 0 12 Jan * 2022,0 0 29 Jan * 2022,0 0 1 Feb * 2022,0 0 14 Feb * 2022,0 0 15 Mar * 2022,0 0 17 May * 2022 ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically schedule an AWS Lambda for one time execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467768/programmatically-schedule-an-aws-lambda-for-one-time-execution)

Comment: I need to trigger the lambda on multiple specific dates using the same eventbridge scheduler. One time execution is out of scope

Comment: What happened when you tried the code you added in the edit?